# Where can I find a sample logconfig.json for EventStore?

Tags: logging, config, eventstoredb

EventStore has moved its logging config to a file called `logconfig.json`, but I can't find a sample of what this file should look like, so I'm forced to have no file at all, and use EventStore's default logging config.

I've googled all over. Where can I find a sample of `logconfig.json` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [find one](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/blob/3a79cfbb4b4a1488fd9ec8dab0ff6b2d668f728f/src/EventStore.Common/Log/logconfig.json) in the EventStoreDB repository.

It is a normal `appconfig.json`-style file that only contains the ASP.NET Core [logging configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-logging) settings.

Here's the default config:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Warning",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Grpc": "Fatal"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also [see here](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/blob/3de8117466c0c92922eaaa986bbd2103f0b8d9f3/src/EventStore.Common/Log/EventStoreLoggerConfiguration.cs#L87) that if the `Serilog` section is found in the file, it will be used to configure Serilog, instead of using the hard-coded configuration. The section format should be following the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--) of the Serilog appsetting configuration provider.